# Preposition Hayday

Tags: riddle

I'm all over.

Over you. Under you. Through you.
< Insert Evil Laugh >

I love black holes and dying cosmos.
I come from evil politicians and ruthless dictators.
I come from silly children and irresponsible criminals.

I can cause horrible diseases.
The government overregulates me.
But that doesn't stop me.

Mwah Ha Ha.

Nothing can stop me.
Not walls. Not floors. Not Time or Space or Distance.
I OWN THE WORLD!!!

Not that it does me much good.
Sometimes I think of my existence as a giant treadmill.

Hint:
Focus on these lines: (Though the correct answer will satisfy ALL clues.)

> Nothing can stop me. Not time or...distance.
> The government regulates me. 
> It can (but often doesn't) cause horrible diseases.
> And disregard the evil laughter. It's just there for comic effect and to make the case more stark. This is not actually evil at all. Nor does it literally "own the world."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're

> radiation

I'm all over.

> Radiation is [everywhere](http://www.nrc.gov/about-nrc/radiation/around-us/doses-daily-lives.html)

Over you. Under you. Through you.
< Insert Evil Laugh >

> See above

I love black holes and dying cosmos.

> *"[Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) is black-body radiation that is predicted to be released by black holes, due to quantum effects near the event horizon."*

I come from evil politicians and ruthless dictators.

> States worldwide have used or threatened to use nuclear weapons

I come from silly children and irresponsible criminals.
I can cause horrible diseases.

> Exposure to certain types of radiation can cause cancer

The government overregulates me.

> I don't know enough to claim *over*-regulation, but many governments have some form of [nuclear regulation](http://www.nrc.gov/about-nrc/radiation/protects-you/reg-matls.html) in effect

But that doesn't stop me.

Mwah Ha Ha.

Nothing can stop me.
Not walls. Not floors. Not Time or Space or Distance.
I OWN THE WORLD!!!

> [Certain types of radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-ionizing_radiation) can pass through walls, floors, and over great distances of space.

Not that it does me much good.
Sometimes I think of my existence as a giant treadmill.

Comment: "I love black holes and dying cosmos" - Hawking radiation?

Comment: @alex oh gosh, I almost linked that but didn't for some reason, I'll add it when I get a chance

Answer (score 7):

> Death

I'm all over.

Over you. Under you.

> Death is everywhere in relation to someone

Through you.
< Insert Evil Laugh >

> Whether people want to admit it or not, they cause death.

I love black holes and dying cosmos.

> Causing the death of any life nearby

I come from evil politicians and ruthless dictators.

> War

I come from silly children

> Children love to kill bugs, whether stomping or otherwise; additionally, just playing will cause things like plants and small creatures to die (often by accident, and to the parents' chagrin)

and irresponsible criminals.

> Murder is indeed a crime

I can cause horrible diseases.

> Many diseases are caused by the decay of a body

The government overregulates me.

> Much debate occurs around when someone or a pet is allowed to die, from executions to abortion to suicide to war to assisted suicide...

But that doesn't stop me.

> People still die

Mwah Ha Ha.

> Mwah Ha Ha!

Nothing can stop me.

> "Nothing is certain except for death and taxes."

Not walls. Not floors. Not Time or Space or Distance.

> Walls can't keep out death, whether from disease or natural causes.
>  It doesn't matter how high up you are in the world (floors), you will still die.
>  Indeed, the longer you live and the more you experience, your chance of experiencing death in the near future increases.

I OWN THE WORLD!!!

> Most of the Earth we are familiar with (i.e., rocks, soil) has at one point been part of a living being. The world as we know it is very much made of dead things.

Not that it does me much good.

> What does something that is dead care?

Sometimes I think of my existence as a giant treadmill.

> Circle of life/death

Answer (score 5):

You're:

> Entropy *aka* disorder

Because:

> You're everywhere - first and second law of thermodynamics.
>  You create black holes and cause cosmos to die.
>  Evil politicians, silly children, criminals,  *etc* create *disorder*.
>  Disorder of the human body causes *all* diseases.
>  Governments try to establish *order* but that doesn't stop the laws of thermodynamics.
>   Which state that **Entropy** is always *increasing*.
>  It does you no good because **Entropy** doesn't control anything - quite the opposite.
>  And a treadmill has to create **Entropy** too.

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> Greed

Because:

I'm all over. Over you. Under you. Through you.

> Greed is everywhere

I love black holes and dying cosmos.

> Black holes suck up everything for themselves and dying cosmos can make black holes.

I come from evil politicians and ruthless dictators.

> Evil politicians and dictators (greedy beyond belief)

I come from silly children and irresponsible criminals.

> Children always want more "But I want it!!!", and criminals steal

I can cause horrible disease.

> Greed can cause famine by uneven distribution of wealth.

The government over regulates me.

> They break up monopolies, but they are also greedy.

Nothing can stop me.

> Greed has been around a long time and very likely isn't going anywhere any time soon.

I OWN THE WORLD!

> Greedy much?

Not that it does me much good. I think of my existence as a giant treadmill.

> Treadmill --> people who are greedy always want more no matter how much they have.

Answer (score 2):

You are an

> **Idea**

I'm all over. Over you. Under you. Through you.

> Ideas are everywhere

I love black holes and dying cosmos. I come from evil politicians and ruthless dictators. I come from silly children and irresponsible criminals.

> A lot of thought, Ideas have been out there about black holes, cosmoses, what happens inside a black hole and they fascinate mankind very much. Evil politicians, dictators, silly children and criminal have only one thing in common: an idea (although the type of idea may differ).

I can cause horrible diseases. The government over regulates me. But that doesn't stop me.

> It only takes an idea to start a cigarette or mix something in the water which can led to horrible diseases. You try to implement a really crazy idea but there are lot of rules and regulations that will not stop you.

Nothing can stop me. Not walls. Not floors. Not Time or Space or Distance.
I OWN THE WORLD!!!

> An idea is unstoppable.

Not that it does me much good. Sometimes I think of my existence as a giant treadmill.

> You **think** of your existence as a giant treadmill. You can think anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are :

> Gravity

I'm all over.

> No denying it, just because we don't feel it's effects everywhere, it is omnipresent.

Over you. Under you. Through you.

> See above.

I love black holes and dying cosmos.

> Strongest in these areas.

I come from evil politicians and ruthless dictators.

> People often gravitate towards the history and characters of notorious politicians and dictators etc. Just look at how much we know about Hitler.

I come from silly children and irresponsible criminals.

> I guess there is (or can be) an endearment towards these characters although I will admit, it's a stretch.

I can cause horrible diseases.

> Brittle bone syndrome (Osteogenesis imperfecta) will be massively affected by gravity or lack thereof.

The government overregulates me.
But that doesn't stop me.

> Flights and aeronautic regulation after ever crash or accident.

Nothing can stop me.
Not walls. Not floors. Not Time or Space or Distance.

> Self explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best fit is:

> Misinformation

I'm all over.

Over you. Under you. Through you.

> There are myths, lies and inaccuracies everywhere. I often find that things I believed have been proven untrue. (Are eggs good for you? The answer seems to change every ten years.)

I love black holes and dying cosmos.

> I take this figuratively. Mistaken ideas can be a huge drain of time and energy.

I come from evil politicians and ruthless dictators.
I come from silly children and irresponsible criminals.

> These are all examples of people who spread misinformation deliberately or through ignorance.

I can cause horrible diseases.

> Mistaken beliefs about sanitation or sexual contact can cause epidemics.

The government overregulates me.
But that doesn't stop me.

> There are many laws regarding libel, slander and truth in advertising but misinformation is still rampant.

Nothing can stop me.
Not walls. Not floors. Not Time or Space or Distance.

> This is very true of misinformation. It is spread by every medium. You can even argue that distance increases the effect as information can be further garbled as it is passed from person to person.

I OWN THE WORLD!!!

> This may in itself be a piece of misinformation.

Not that it does me much good.

> There is little ultimate benefit to misinformation, even if it is well-intended like the "instructive fairy tales" people sometimes tell children.

Sometimes I think of my existence as a giant treadmill.

> It does seem like a huge, meaningless waste of effort: all the time that people spend generating and spreading misinformation.

Comment: This is my favorite answer

Answer (score -1):

It is

> A Time MAchine

Because

> Because a time machine could cause a new disease or cancer. If it could teleport anywhere and to anytime it could change things or cause wars and the government wouldn't want that. Black Holes are pretty much what make time machines teleport.

Comment: `Black Holes are pretty much what make time machines teleport.` — Damn it! I knew my time machine wouldn't work for some reason! Shouldn't have missed that lecture!

Answer (score -1):

It's

> Energy.

I'm all over.

> Energy.

Over you. Under you. Through you.

> Energy.

I love black holes and dying cosmos.

> ...both of which involve enormous amounts of energy.

I come from evil politicians and ruthless dictators.

> It takes a lot of energy to maintain a fascist totalitarianism.

I come from silly children and irresponsible criminals.

> Again, energy. Silly children have loads of it, and irresponsible criminals use a lot making rash decisions.

I can cause horrible diseases.

> Energy causes **everything**.

The government overregulates me.

> DEFINITELY energy.

But that doesn't stop me.

> Of course not. Energy never stops.

Nothing can stop me.

> Energy.

Not walls. Not floors. Not Time or Space or Distance.

> Energy.

I OWN THE WORLD!!!

> Yep. Everything is owned by energy.

Not that it does me much good.

> Well, when you ARE everything, nothing does you much good.

Sometimes I think of my existence as a giant treadmill.

> Yep. Energy is constantly moving at a constant speed (the speed of light).